# How to access individual elements in a 2d array c++

Tags: c++, arrays

Basically, I have a 2d array and I would like to fill those elements using a for loop. Here is a rough set up (that is not working):

```
int grid[rows][columns];
for (int i=0; i < rows; i++){
    grid[rows][i] = 0;
    for (int j=0; j < columns; j++){
        grid[columns][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

I have a working grid that the user determines. So basically if the user inputs a row and column that is x by x it'll work. The issue comes because it prints out random numbers at time in the formant of the grid. So sometimes it'll print out:

4 4 4 4

4 4 4 4

4 4 4 4

I am trying to get a grid that looks like:

0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0

I am making the 2d array first and then I am trying to fill the elements with 0. That is why I am using the for loop. The outcome is to fill every element with 0. It's just not working for some reason. I have no idea...

Any suggestions will help! Thank you

Comment: Use your debugger, stop on each line where you assign 0. Check and make a note of the position in the array where you're assigning 0 by checking the values of the indexes you're using. Your bug should be glaringly obvious when you notice that you're re-assigning the same target indices.

Comment: Hint, check that you are writing within the array bounds.

Answer (score 5):

You are accessing the 2D array incorrectly.  Try this instead:

```
int grid[rows][columns];

for (int i=0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j < columns; j++)
    {
        grid[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

As for why you are getting non zero data, it could be because there is random data in the 2D array, either leftover from your code or there because it was never initialized.